# Set an array length of state to 0, but binding list has still one element left

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This TODO list is the third demo from React.js official site,
and I made a extra feature: **'clear all issues'**.

It just calls `this.setState({ items: [] })`,
but there is still one `li` remain on html page after doing this.

This situation can be reproduced at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddhp/Lhdo96fw/ , by clicking on *clear all*.

This is a very simple implementation so I can't figure out the reason.
I have checked `this.state.items` and it's `[]`.

If someone knows the root cause, It will be very appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to your `onSubmit` method to be called after the `clearAll` one.

Just add a `event.preventDefault();` in your `clearAll` will prevent your form to be submitted and thus creating an empty element.